# I need to compare double word numbers

Tags: assembly, emu8086

Task:
LongInt. Count how many numbers in array satisfy the condition : c<=A[i]<=d.
I have this code sample, but it does not work correctly. The answer should be 3 but it's 6. How do I change compare between two numbers?

```
.model tiny
org 100h
.data
vec dd -2,-6,-5,-4,4,-3
N dd  6
c dd -4
d dd  -2 
x dd 0
m1 dd 0 
.code
mov di,1;index
result:
mov ax,vec[di]
mov [x],ax
cmp ax,0
jnge negative
inc di
cmp di,N
jz end
negative:
cmp ax,[c]
jge greater_than_c
greater_than_c:
cmp ax,[d]
jle less_than_b
less_than_b:
inc m1
inc di
cmp di,N
jl result 
jz end
end: 
mov ax,m1 
ret
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not written in English

Comment: I rewrote question in English.

Comment: "it does not work correctly" is insufficient description of a problem

Comment: The answer should be 3, not 6.

Comment: Addresses are in bytes.  `mov ax,vec[di]` will load `ax` with the word that is `di` bytes past the address `vec`.  Since they are 4-byte dwords, starting at 1 and adding 1 to di every time doesn't make sense.  I think you need to be loading two words (into two registers) so that you have the whole dword to work with.

Comment: A good start is to single step with your debugger and see exactly what is happening throughout your code.  If you don't have a debugger installed, or don't know how to use it, remedy that first before proceeding.  Fixing your code will be orders of magnitude harder without that tool.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I replaced `inc di` with `add di,4`  which fixed the array movement. But the result is still wrong. I don't really get how do I load and compare two words into two registers. I got an advice that a need to compare numbers one word at a time. Not sure how do I do that.

Comment: Just like you'd use `sub`/`sbb` to do a dword subtract in two steps, you need `cmp` / `sbb`  to emulate a dword compare.  Look at C compiler output (for 64-bit integers in 32-bit mode) for the same algorithm.  https://godbolt.org/z/crPYb3Kf8